# Drunken man walking on an axis

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions

> A drunken man walks randomly along an axis with the points $0, \pm 1, \pm 2, \ldots$. He begins from point zero and in each step he moves in a length of $1$ to the positive side with a probability of $0.4$ or to the negative side with a 
>   probability of $0.6$. The steps are independent. he does a total of 50 steps
>
> What is the probability that he will be on the left of his starting point after $27$ steps?

I tried to calculate this using the binomial distribution with choosing $27$ out of $50$ using the given probabilities and I obtained $0.078$. Is this correct?

the way i'm trying to calculate is with$ \frac{\left(l+r\right)!}{l!r!}lp^lrp^r$ where l is the amount of left steps, r is the amount of right steps, lp is the probability of a left step, rp is the probability of the right step

Comment: Where did the $50$ come from?

Comment: The drunken man has to walk at most 13 steps to the right side. Please show your calculation.

Comment: @Did, what i meant is the probability of the last step being the 27th step to the left direction

Comment: the formula i gave is how i see the walk as a combination of steps to the right and the left with the given probabilities

Comment: "the 27th step to the left direction" OK, but the 27th step amongst how many steps? IOW, "Where did the 50 come from?"

Comment: a drunken man does a total of 50 steps. the question is what is the probability that in the last step, the 50th step, it will also be the 27th to the negative(left)

Comment: @did - i caught my mistake, i did not say that he does a total of 50 steps. i am very sorry for that

Comment: Hmmm... so, are you asking for the probability that their 50th step is the 27th they are taking to the left? Then the answer is obviously $${49\choose26}(0.6)^{26}(0.4)^{49-26}(0.6)$$

Comment: @Did i thought the same in the beginning, but the answer from that formula is larger than 1

Comment: ?? No it is not.

Answer (score 2):

Let $N$ be the random variable representing the number of steps he takes in the negative direction. We say $N\sim\mathrm B(27,0.4)$.

For him to end up on the negative side, he needs to take more steps to the negative than to the positive. In other words, he needs to take at least $14$ steps to the negative. Therefore, you need to calculate $\operatorname{P}(N\ge14)$.

Given that $$X\sim\mathrm B(n,p)\implies \operatorname{P} (X=x) = \binom nx p^x(1-p)^{n-x}$$ and that $$\operatorname{P}(a\le X\le b)=\sum_{x=a}^b \operatorname{P} (X=x)$$ can you continue?

---

If you need to see the answer and think backwards, here it is:

> $$\sum_{x=14}^{27} \binom{27}x(0.4)^x(0.6)^{27-x}$$

Comment: i'm sorry but i don't understand. if i look at the walk as a combination, don't i need to calculate it as: $\:\frac{50!}{27!\left(50-23\right)!}0.6^{27}0.4^{23}$ ?

Comment: tried to represent the walk as a combination of the steps and the given probabilities, i.e $\frac{\left(l+r\right)!}{l!r!}lp^lrp^r$ where l is the amount of left steps, r is the amount of right steps, lp is the probability of a left step, rp is the probability of the right step

Comment: @BeginningMath Yes, that second comment is on the right track! Remember that you need a **sum** of probabilities, because $14$ steps negative **and** $15$ steps negative **and** $\cdots$ **and** $27$ steps negative all satisfy the condition.

Comment: how can i do that using the combination representation i've just given? is it correct?

Comment: @BeginningMath See my edit

Comment: so i wasn't far at all! thank you so much! (regarding the second comment)

Comment: what is the final result you've obtained? i couldn't find any online calculators that allow me to translate it into a numbered result

Comment: @BeginningMath Desmos gives $14.47\%$

Answer (score 1):

All you have to show is, after 27 steps, steps to the left is greater than steps to the right.

The probability of that is $27C14*0.6^{14}*0.4^{13} + 27C15*0.6^{15}*0.4^{12}.........27C27*0.6^{27}$. On a TI-83 or similar its 1 - binomcdf with an input of 27,0.6,13. That is, what is the probability of getting at least 14 lefts out of 27. I get close to p = .855

Comment: thank you so much!

Comment: There was an error in input. Using the complementary rule requires an input of (27,0.6,13) where 13 is (27 - 14). Its 1 - binomcdf which is 1 minus the probability of getting at most 13 which is equal to the probability of getting at least 14. p = .855.